# Danish letters are disappearing with MathJax 3

Tags: mathjax

I'd like to use the letters æ, ø and å as text in MathJax 3.

The colors "red", "green" and "blue" are spelled "rød", "grøn" and "blå" 
so they are hard to avoid...

[image: Example of letters missing]

In the image you can see that the danish letters disappear, when I write:

```
\text{grøn}   \text{blå}    etc
```

UPDATE

The answer of scraaappy made me try

```
   src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@"@"3/es5/tex-mml-chtml.js"
```

instead of

```
   src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@"@"3/es5/tex-svg-full.js"
```

and now the danish characters appear.

My setup is somewhat involved, so I'll try to make a minimal example that shows the problem using `tex-svg-full.js`.

I notice that the danish letters look odd when using `tex-mml-chtml.js`
so my theory is that the TeX Font used by MathJax 3 does not contain danish characters - and the fallback solution is coded differently in `tex-mml-chtml.js` and ``tex-svg-full.js`.

Here is an example that shows danish characters when using `tex-mml-chtml.js`.

[image]

Is there a list of letters in the font used by MathJax 2 available somewhere?

UPDATE 2

A minimal example, which doesn't show missing characters (in the real
setup the MathJax is rendered using `MathJax.typesetClear()` followed by `MathJax.typeset()`. The example shows that the danish characters aren't in the math font. The output isn't pretty.

[Minimal Example in JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4p5mvLxs/)

Comment: Did you try different output options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>This is not a MathJax issue. Without any more precision it is difficult to answer but if you attempt to display in HTML check if you're in HTML5 and/or if your charset encoding is set to UTF-8</s>

```html
<script id="MathJax-script" async
 src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-svg.js"></script>
 
 $$\text{grøn}  $$
 
 \(\text{grøn} \)
```

EDIT

Below a screenshot of the result I obtain from the second snippet (same in your fiddle)

[image]

Is it what you've got ?

After [reading the doc](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/output/fonts.html), the conclusion might be to use the [unicode extension](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/input/tex/extensions/unicode.html) which let you choose your own font, or try something with `\class` (with which I did not obtain much success!)

```css
.test{
  color: red;
  font-size: 2em;
  letter-spacing: 15px;
  line-height: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script >
      MathJax = { tex:       {packages:    {'[+]': ['physics','unicode']},
                              inlineMath:  [ ['$','$'],   ["\\(","\\)"] ],
                              displayMath: [ ['$$','$$'], ["\\[","\\]"] ]},
                  svg:       {scale: 100},
                  loader:    {load: ['[tex]/physics','[tex]/unicode']},
                  styles:    {".MathJax_SVG_Display":
                                 { "text-align":       "center",
                                   "margin":           "0.25em 0em ! important"}}
                };
   </script>
    <!-- Title -->
    <title>Testing danish characters in MathJax 3 </title>

  <h1> MathJax formula in original page. </h1>
 \[ x aæbøcå y \unicode{0216} \]
\[ x aæbøcå y \unicode[Garamond]{0216} \]

\[ x aæbøcå y \unicode[Verdana]{0216} \]

\[ aæbøcå \class{test}{Ø} \]


    <script id="MathJax-script" async
       src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-svg-full.js">
    </script>
```

Comment: See the update in the answer. I am using the correct doctype and the charset encoding is utf-8.

Comment: It's worth noting that I am using `MathJax.typesetClear()` followed by `MathJax.typeset()` to rerender the math on the page.

Comment: I think you are right: I need to look into embedding "normal characters" into the MathJax output. Version 3 unfortunately doesn't allow one to specify a default font for unicode.